# How to page break in long author list? APA6

Tags: page-breaking, pandoc, author, apa6, rmarkdown

I've been trying to knit an article with a very long author list using RMarkdown Pandoc. But the long list seems not to start on a new page. Half of them cannot be shown on the first page since it's too long. How can I solve this?
Here's an easy replicate of the codes with the problem. Also with the generated pdf.

The code seems long but it's very easy to read since it's just example names and affiliations.

I used repeated names and affiliations here for just demonstration. The problem still exists when I use proper names and affiliations.

[image: generated pdf]

this is what I hope to have:
[image: expected pdf]

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
  9pt,
  ,jou,floatsintext]{apa6}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math} % this also loads fontspec
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}
\ifPDFTeX\else
  % xetex/luatex font selection
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\VerbBar}{|}
\newcommand{\VERB}{\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
% Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
\newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.94,0.16,0.16}{#1}}
\newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.64,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.81,0.36,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{#1}}
\newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.81,0.36,0.00}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{#1}}
\newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
% Make \paragraph and \subparagraph free-standing
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
  \let\oldparagraph\paragraph
  \renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
  \let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
  \renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifLuaTeX
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\else
\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}
\fi
\babelprovide[main,import]{english}
% get rid of language-specific shorthands (see #6817):
\let\LanguageShortHands\languageshorthands
\def\languageshorthands#1{}
% Manuscript styling
\usepackage{upgreek}
\captionsetup{font=singlespacing,justification=justified}

% Table formatting
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
% \usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}   % Landscape page setup for large tables
\usepackage{multirow}       % Table styling
\usepackage{tabularx}       % Control Column width
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}  % Allows for three part tables with a specified notes section
\usepackage{threeparttablex}            % Lets threeparttable work with longtable

% Create new environments so endfloat can handle them
% \newenvironment{ltable}
%   {\begin{landscape}\centering\begin{threeparttable}}
%   {\end{threeparttable}\end{landscape}}
\newenvironment{lltable}{\begin{landscape}\centering\begin{ThreePartTable}}{\end{ThreePartTable}\end{landscape}}

% Enables adjusting longtable caption width to table width
% Solution found at http://golatex.de/longtable-mit-caption-so-breit-wie-die-tabelle-t15767.html
\makeatletter
\newcommand\LastLTentrywidth{1em}
\newlength\longtablewidth
\setlength{\longtablewidth}{1in}
\newcommand{\getlongtablewidth}{\begingroup \ifcsname LT@\roman{LT@tables}\endcsname \global\longtablewidth=0pt \renewcommand{\LT@entry}[2]{\global\advance\longtablewidth by ##2\relax\gdef\LastLTentrywidth{##2}}\@nameuse{LT@\roman{LT@tables}} \fi \endgroup}

% \setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
% \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

% Overwrite redefinition of paragraph and subparagraph by the default LaTeX template
% See https://github.com/crsh/papaja/issues/292
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\parindent}%
  {0\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\itshape\typesectitle}}

\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{1em}%
  {0\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
  {-\z@\relax}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape\hspace{\parindent}{#1}\textit{\addperi}}{\relax}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\section{\normalfont\normalsize\abstractname}}
  {\section*{\normalfont\normalsize\abstractname}}
  {}{\typeout{Failed to patch abstract.}}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\section{\protect\normalfont{\@title}}}
  {\section*{\protect\normalfont{\@title}}}
  {}{\typeout{Failed to patch title.}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd\appendix
  {\xapptocmd\section
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname\ifoneappendix\else~\theappendix\fi\\: #1}}
    {}{\InnerPatchFailed}%
  }
{}{\PatchFailed}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}


\usepackage{csquotes}
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Whole day tring to solve this problem},
  pdfauthor={John M. Smith1, Marton Kovacs2, 1 1 3, 2 23, 3 34, 4 43, 5 55, 6 66, 7 74, 8 83, 9 97, 10 108, 11 119, 12 1210, 13 1311, 14 141, 15 152, 16 163, 17 173, 18 184, 19 193, 20 205, 21 216, 22 224, 23 233, 24 247, 25 258, 26 269, 27 2710, 28 2811, 29 291, 30 302, 31 313, 32 323, 33 334, 34 343, 35 355, 36 3612, 37 3713, 38 3814, 39 3915, 40 408, 41 4116, 42 4210, 43 4311, 44 4416, 45 452, 46 463, 47 473, 48 4817, 49 493, 50 507, 51 5118, 52 524, 53 533, 54 547, 55 558, 56 569, 57 5710, 58 5811, 59 5919, \& 60 6020},
  pdflang={en-EN},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}

\title{\textbf{Whole day tring to solve this problem}}
\author{John M. Smith\textsuperscript{1}, Marton Kovacs\textsuperscript{2}, 1 1 \newpage\textsuperscript{3}, 2 2\textsuperscript{3}, 3 3\textsuperscript{4}, 4 4\textsuperscript{3}, 5 5\textsuperscript{5}, 6 6\textsuperscript{6}, 7 7\textsuperscript{4}, 8 8\textsuperscript{3}, 9 9\textsuperscript{7}, 10 10\textsuperscript{8}, 11 11\textsuperscript{9}, 12 12\textsuperscript{10}, 13 13\textsuperscript{11}, 14 14\textsuperscript{1}, 15 15\textsuperscript{2}, 16 16\textsuperscript{3}, 17 17\textsuperscript{3}, 18 18\textsuperscript{4}, 19 19\textsuperscript{3}, 20 20\textsuperscript{5}, 21 21\textsuperscript{6}, 22 22\textsuperscript{4}, 23 23\textsuperscript{3}, 24 24\textsuperscript{7}, 25 25\textsuperscript{8}, 26 26\textsuperscript{9}, 27 27\textsuperscript{10}, 28 28\textsuperscript{11}, 29 29\textsuperscript{1}, 30 30\textsuperscript{2}, 31 31\textsuperscript{3}, 32 32\textsuperscript{3}, 33 33\textsuperscript{4}, 34 34\textsuperscript{3}, 35 35\textsuperscript{5}, 36 36\textsuperscript{12}, 37 37\textsuperscript{13}, 38 38\textsuperscript{14}, 39 39\textsuperscript{15}, 40 40\textsuperscript{8}, 41 41\textsuperscript{16}, 42 42\textsuperscript{10}, 43 43\textsuperscript{11}, 44 44\textsuperscript{16}, 45 45\textsuperscript{2}, 46 46\textsuperscript{3}, 47 47\textsuperscript{3}, 48 48\textsuperscript{17}, 49 49\textsuperscript{3}, 50 50\textsuperscript{7}, 51 51\textsuperscript{18}, 52 52\textsuperscript{4}, 53 53\textsuperscript{3}, 54 54\textsuperscript{7}, 55 55\textsuperscript{8}, 56 56\textsuperscript{9}, 57 57\textsuperscript{10}, 58 58\textsuperscript{11}, 59 59\textsuperscript{19}, \& 60 60\textsuperscript{20}}
\date{}


\shorttitle{SHORT TITLE}

\authornote{

Correspondence concerning this article should be addressed to John M. Smith, Enter postal address here.

}

\affiliation{\vspace{0.5cm}\textsuperscript{1} School of Psychology, University of Sydney, Sydney, Australia\\\textsuperscript{2} Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology\\
\newpage
\textsuperscript{3} Institute of Psycchology, ELTE Eotvos Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology\\\textsuperscript{4} Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologya\\\textsuperscript{5} Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa\\\textsuperscript{6} Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Laoranda University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology\\\textsuperscript{7} Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa\\\textsuperscript{8} Institute of Psycholaogy, ELTE Eotvos Laoranda University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology\\\textsuperscript{9} Institute of Psycchology, ELTE Eotvos Lorand University, Budapaest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology\\\textsuperscript{10} Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Lorand Universaity, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologya\\\textsuperscript{11} Institute of Psycahology, ELTE Eotvos Loranda University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology\\\textsuperscript{12} Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Laoran1da University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology\\\textsuperscript{13} Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Loran2d University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologya\\\textsuperscript{14} Institute of Psycchology, ELTE Eotvos Loran3d University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyInstitute of Psycchology, ELTE Eotvos Loran3d University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology\\\textsuperscript{15} Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa\\\textsuperscript{16} Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa\\\textsuperscript{17} Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa\\\textsuperscript{18} Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Laoranda University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa\\\textsuperscript{19} aInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa\\\textsuperscript{20} vInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\subsection{R Markdown}\label{r-markdown}

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see \url{http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com}.

When you click the \textbf{Knit} button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\FunctionTok{summary}\NormalTok{(cars)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{verbatim}
##      speed           dist       
##  Min.   : 4.0   Min.   :  2.00  
##  1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 26.00  
##  Median :15.0   Median : 36.00  
##  Mean   :15.4   Mean   : 42.98  
##  3rd Qu.:19.0   3rd Qu.: 56.00  
##  Max.   :25.0   Max.   :120.00
\end{verbatim}

\subsection{Including Plots}\label{including-plots}

You can also embed plots, for example:

\includegraphics{AJP_test_files/figure-latex/pressure-1.pdf}

Note that the \texttt{echo\ =\ FALSE} parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Given that this is a TeX issue, consider including the resulting TeX code in your question (rather than the R Markdown document); this may increase your chances to receive a useful answer.

Comment: Starting from ID 14 or so, the institutions in the markdown are doubled or repeated multiple times per entry. Why is this? This is likely causing the output to look like this.

Comment: the repeated names and institutions are just for demonstration. the problem still exists when I use proper institutions with no repeats

Comment: @ArjenH: Can you mock up what you'd like the output to look like knowing that there's going to be a page break somewhere? It's not clear just from your discussion what you want it to look like. Currently you just mention "the long list [does not seem to] start a new page."

Comment: @Werner: Sure! I've just added the expected one